# How to find a secret case within a case?

Tags: another-case-solved

Some major cases in the iOS game *Another Case Solved* have a question mark attached to them, and they say

> There is a secret case to be found during this investigation

How are those secret cases found?

The cases which have secret cases to be found inside them are: Valued Vinyl, Disappearing Daughter, Tedious Testament and Jittery Judge.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "secret cases" are found in the missions during the investigation. So far I have found 2 investigations that have secret cases:

- Valued Vinyl:

> The secret case is unlocked in the rooms mission, you need to get into storage where you get the Paper Clip tool which unlocks rooms. You can then get into the Employee lounge where a recording is hidden inside the locker, which unlocks the bonus case (and some sweets hidden there too). <sub>Found with the help of [toucharcade](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?s=05a7aa988f65c2844cac306b3b9723c7&p=3143667)</sub>

- Disappearing Daughter:

> The secret case is unlocked in the map mission, when revealing the barber shop on the top left corner, the barber will offer a new investigation.

- Tedious Testament:

> The secret case is unlocked in the rooms mission on the right of the church, on the bulletin board, there is a ,message which opens a new case. Pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMoKO.png)

- Jittery Judge:

> The secret case is unlocked in the rooms mission, in the office, inside the middle desk there is a file, this file unlocks the secret case.

Answer (score 1):

You find the secret case while you are searching through the rooms. For example, in Valued Vinyl, go to the storage room and find the paper clip. That will add a new tool to your inventory that allows you to unlock rooms. Unlock the Employee room and find the record in the locker. That will unlock the secret case. Make sure you have some timers to add more time since unlocking a door takes up 10 seconds. I assume the rest of the secret cases are found in a similar way. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of disappearing daughter, I found the secret case on the map. I revealed all icons on or adjoining railways and revealed the barber shop on the left corner, two icons in on the top line.

Comment: In tedious testament, the hidden case "Vengeful Vampire" can be found while searching the church. Go into the courtyard out the back entrance of the church (2nd area down on the right side). There is an ad board, search the piece of paper.

Comment: In Jittery Judge, you can find the secret case Prohibited Piñatas while searching for the file. Go into the office, search middle desk, and open the file folder.